# What command can actually clear the terminal screen?

Tags: terminal

In either Cygwin or gnome terminal, `clear` doesn't actually remove the previous output in the terminal. So when I run `clear` and then some programs, and search (using the search feature of the terminals) for some word in the output of the programs that are run after `clear` , it will also search in the output of the other commands previously run on the screen before `clear`.

How can i search in the output on a terminal screen since an arbitrarily chosen time point?

My current workaround is to open a new terminal to run the programs whose outputs I would like to search in. But is there a way without opening a new terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't AFAIK really doable, because searchable terminal history is entirely a clientside thing.  You could look into modifying the terminal emulator to accept a certain escape sequence to purge the entire history, but I don't know of any that offer this functionality out of the box.

Comment: `tput clear` seems to do it, but I dont know why and I didn't test searching.

Comment: @ctx `tput clear` is the same as `clear`

Comment: Alternately you can use script(1) to save a copy of the session in a file and search that. i.e. script; ./prog1; ./prog2; exit; grep word typescript; rm typescript

Comment: `tput init` or `tput reset`, depending on the capabilities of the terminal. Sometimes `reset` works as well.

Comment: Other, more direct, questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26975/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375743/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87469/ .

Answer (score -1):

The features that you're mentioning sound very similar to what GNU Screen provides.

If you wish to search terminal output then you can make use of the copy-mode/scrollback feature. (CTRL-a ESC) then ? to reverse search and / to forward search.

I spend a very large (close to 100%) of my terminal time in GNU Screen.

By default the scroll back is set to 100 lines, this is easily increased by setting `defscrollback` to something higher in `~/.screenrc`. New windows can be created (CTRL-a c) and switched between (CTRL-a n, or CTRL-a p).

It's something that has been around for decades and I hope it will be around for many more to come due to the vast array of features it provides which gives me a consistent layer no matter which terminal is flavour of the month.

Comment: I think this is the opposite of what the OP desires. They do not want the shell history search to include commands that have been followed by `clear`.

Comment: Then destroy the window. CTRL-a k or CTRL-d. Scroll back is there for searching or destroying.

Comment: Not a good answer, the user, and others, want to know what the module is inside of the terminal to control the rendering without having to close and open a new window. clear, reset and history -c do not clear the searchable history within the terminal.